# Some questions about QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, non-perturbative, large-n

About QCD, I have two questions. I know I should propose one question one time, but they are actually two steps of the same question: Non-perturbative aspects of QCD.

1, Why do we need to solve QCD exactly?
Of course, solving any field theory exactly is a dream. But what I mean is why do we feel more urgent to solve exactly QCD than other theories such as $\phi^4$ theory? Is the reason that perturbation can not be used in QCD in some cases such as the confinement problem?

2, Why do we need the large N expansion?
People say that QCD is a zero-parameter theory because the coupling constant $g$ is changing with the RG flow. And to do a first approximation, we should introduce a parameter to expand in. The parameter turns out to be the $N$ in $SU(N)$. But similar arguments can be given for $\phi^4$ theory where the coupling $\lambda$ is also a RG flow dependent quantity. Then why do we naturally and comfortably expand in $\lambda$ there? And even after we introduce the large N expansion, we still do the analysis with the help of feynman diagrams which means that we already use the perturbation theory. So does it mean that the argument 'large N limit is introduced because QCD is a zero-parameter theory' incorrect and actually it is introduced simply for simplifying the calculations?

I really appreciate if someone can discuss these issus here.

The second question has been answered [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/36434/why-do-we-need-the-large-n-expansion). And I think the answer to the first question is exactly what I guessed in this post, partly also because QCD is very important.

Comment: Hi Wein - could you edit your post to make it clear what one question you're asking that these are the two steps of? Right now I think the connection is not so clear.

Comment: Ok, if you think they are not related with each other clearly, I can divide this post into two ones. But I just think that that will weaken the motivation for these questions and make discussions somewhat repeated in two posts.

Comment: Who says solving QCD *exactly* is a priority? In fact, who is even trying to do that?

Comment: @MitchellPorter Solving QCD exactly is one the seven Clay Institutes's Millennium Problems.

Comment: @Wein Eld - I thought the problem is to prove that the theory is mathematically well-defined and that it exhibits confinement.

Comment: If the second question has been addressed elsewhere, it's best to just remove it from the post entirely and make this just about the first question.

Comment: @Davidz This post has already been closed and the answer is form other website instead physicsSE. I just cleared up my posts.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm just clarifying what you would have to do to get this post reopened.

Comment: @DavidZ, Thank you. But I think is not necessary to reopen it now. I just hope I can read my posts. Then it is ok.

Comment: It would still help the site, and other people who have similar questions, to edit the post so that it would get reopened. But if you really don't care about getting your post reopened, that's your call.